# const already declared in ES6 switch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, ecmascript-6

Consider the file `sample.es6`

```
switch (1) {
    case 1:
        const foo = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        const foo = 2;
        break;
}
```

If I run it with Node I got

```
$ node --version
v4.2.11
$ node sample.es6 
/tmp/sample.es6:6
const foo = 2;
^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/sample.es6:1:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

Why I'm getting this error? Node shouldn't evaluate `const foo = 2;`.

Comment: What are you trying to do after all? Where do you want to use `foo`?

Comment: Are you confused about `const` in general, or why it throws an error when they are in separate `case` sections?

Comment: This was the minimal example that I could provide. I will pass `foo` to functions. Why it throws an error when they are in separate case sections.

Comment: @RaniereSilva: A `case` section doesn't have it's own scope, so multiple declarations of `foo` in them will collide with each other. You can wrap them in blocks (`{ … }`) though to solve this.

Answer (score 81):

You can create scope blocks around your cases, and the compiler will be happy:

```
switch (1) {
    case 1: {
        // notice these extra curly braces
        const foo = 1;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        const foo = 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

Read the [answer from Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397901/2024590) if you need more context.

Comment: javascript, right? 

Comment: Never occurred to me that Switch cases didn't have their own block-scoping by default. Great answer.

Comment: @AlexChoi JS isn't the only language like this. [C++ for one](/q/92396/11107541). [Java for another](/q/10932997/11107541)

Answer (score 21):

You are getting a `SyntaxError` because you are re-declaring a variable in the same scope; a `switch` statement [contains only one underlying block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let), rather than one block per `case`.

JavaScript throws the error at **compile time**. "Node shouldn't evaluate `const foo = 2;`" is irrelevant because this error occurs before Node evaluates anything.

One purpose of `const` (and a lot of new ES6 features, for example the new module spec) is to enable the compiler to do some static analysis. `const` tells the compiler that the variable will never be reassigned, which allows the engine to handle it more efficiently.

Of course, this requires a compile-time check to make sure the variable is indeed never reassigned (or redeclared), which is why you are seeing the error.

Comment: That's one point of `const`. Another one is to prevent me from clobbering my own variables.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that there is only one underlying block in the switch statement. One might guess that there's a block scope per case, which is not... the case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let

Comment: @Christiaan, thanks, I have added this clarification (albeit much later than you pointed it out).

Answer (score 8):

You can use Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) for const assignment:

```
const foo=(function(){
  switch (1) {
    case 1:
      return 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      return 2;
      break;
  }
})();

console.log('foo = '+foo); /* foo = 1 */
```

Altenatively, you can create a scope inside the case with curly braces, but you cannot access the foo outside switch block :

```
switch (1) {
  case 1: {
    const foo = 1;
    console.log(foo+' from inside'); /* 1 from inside */
  } break;
  case 2: {
    const foo = 2;
    console.log(foo+' from inside');
  } break;
}

console.log(foo+' from outside'); /* foo is not defined */
```

Comment: Alternatively to an IIFE, just turn into a function and invoke it explicitly.

Comment: I really like the scoped approach. It looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you'are expecting to create a scope inside **case** statement you should use  **(IIFE)** *Immediately Invoked Function Expression*. It will allow you to create additional scope that you need inside **case** statement.

```
function (value) {
   switch (value) {
     case 1:
       return (function() {
         const foo = 1
         return foo
       }())
       break;
     case 2:
       return (function() {
         const foo = 2
         return foo
       }())
       break;
   }
}
```

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/hermanleus/e4ceq7xt/2/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary variable to determine the value and then set the constant after the value has been determined.

```
let bar;
switch (1) {
    case 1:
        bar = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        bar = 2;
        break;
}
const foo = bar;
```